# NetworkStream.Write and Flush succeeds despite remote socket being closed

Tags: c#, .net, http, tcp, .net-core

I am having an issue where I am trying to write data to a remote TCP server, the connection gets severed, but I am unable to detect when this happens.

My current assumption is that the `WriteAsync` is buffering the data, however I also assume that `FlushAsync` should force it over the wire (and cause an `IOException`).

The real reason why I'm trying to do this is I need to do some low-level HTTP traffic, and I want to verify that the HTTP headers are sent properly before I send the body of the request.

I have a simple unit test to illustrate the issue that I'm facing.

```
public sealed class SocketDisconnectTests
{
    [Fact]
    public async Task ShouldNotWriteIfDisconnected()
    {
        var listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.IPv6Any, 0);

        listener.Server.SetSocketOption(
            SocketOptionLevel.IPv6, 
            SocketOptionName.IPv6Only, 
            false);

        listener.Start();

        try
        {
            // do not await here, let it happen asynchronously
            var readAndCloseTask = ReadAndCloseAsync(listener);

            using (var clientSocket = new Socket(
                SocketType.Stream, 
                ProtocolType.Tcp))
            {
                clientSocket.NoDelay = true;

                await clientSocket.ConnectAsync(
                    "localhost", 
                    ((IPEndPoint) listener.LocalEndpoint).Port);

                using (var clientStream = new NetworkStream(
                    clientSocket, 
                    true))
                {
                    var buf = new byte[] {1, 2, 3, 4};

                    await clientStream.WriteAsync(buf, 0, buf.Length);

                    await clientStream.ReadAsync(buf, 0, buf.Length);

                    Assert.Equal(4, buf[0]);
                    Assert.Equal(3, buf[1]);
                    Assert.Equal(2, buf[2]);
                    Assert.Equal(1, buf[3]);

                    // ensure remote closed the connection
                    await readAndCloseTask;

                    // this assertion always fails as WriteAsync and 
                    // FlushAsync complete without exception
                    await Assert.ThrowsAsync<IOException>(async () =>
                    {
                        await clientStream.WriteAsync(buf, 0, buf.Length);
                        await clientStream.FlushAsync();
                    });
                }
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            listener.Stop();
        }
    }

    private static async Task ReadAndCloseAsync(TcpListener listener)
    {
        using (var socket = await listener.AcceptSocketAsync())
        {
            socket.NoDelay = true;

            using (var stream = new NetworkStream(socket, true))
            {
                var buffer = new byte[4];
                await stream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                var reverse = buffer.Reverse().ToArray();
                await stream.WriteAsync(reverse, 0, reverse.Length);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In short - that's how tcp works, it's not a bug or something - expected behavior.

Comment: Side note: `FlushAsync` (and `Flush`) do nothing on `NetworkStream` (literally - implementation is empty).

Comment: Thanks for the information @Evk, looks like I'll have to do some extra logic on my end to account for this.

Comment: And why do you want to "verify that the HTTP headers are sent properly"? Why not just send body? It will fail fast anyway. For example, if you add another `WriteAsync` in your ThrowsAsync assert (so there will be 2 writes) - second will fail as you expect.

Comment: I'm building an http proxy that has connection pooling, I would like to avoid having to buffer large amounts of data in the proxy itself.  Alternatively I guess I could allow the connection to fail and force the client to resend everything.

Comment: Having fallen afoul of this recently, there is already socket connection pooling built into `HttpClient` and `HttpWebRequest`, so there's no need to re-implement. We had a very weird issue where if connection managed by the connection manager entered a particular bad state (reasons unknown), it stayed that way. Essentially the `KeepAlive` property is reused (it kind of shouldn't be but is), to determine if a fresh socket is created to initiate the request or not. Tweaking or extending `HttpClient` should be enough to do what you need without worrying about the low-level TCP layer.

Comment: @DiskJunky the current implementation is using `HttpClient`, however, I need more fine grained control over how http headers are transmitted which I do not get with `HttpClient`.  (For example differences with WinHttp and curl).

Answer (score 0):

When you're using `socket.NoDelay`, you are turning off the [Nagle algorithm](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.nodelay.aspx#Anchor_2) that would otherwise ensure/verify that the data was received.

By setting `socket.NoDelay`, you said you don't need the ACK that the recipient would otherwise give back once its received the data. If the socket has been told not to look for that ACK, why would it otherwise report on the lack of one?

**EDIT**

Based on the tweaking already applied, `socket.NoDelay` had no effect. Based on the comments in the OP, explicitly trying to manage TCP-level connection pooling is not needed for performing web connections as `WebClient` and `HttpWebRequest` both have a connection manager built in. In the case of `HttpWebRequest`, you can turn off connection pooling (it's on by [default](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/embedded/hh422673(v=msdn.10))), by setting the `KeepAlive` property to `false`.

`HttpClient` also uses a similar [connection pooling](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_5), so rolling your own is unnecessary.

Given that connection pooling is already taken care of, the intent of making sure that the server receives header information before sending the body is best done by simply making 2 web requests, one with the basic header details and another with the main body after the 1st was successful. There shouldn't be a need to work at a TCP level.

Comment: Changing this value made no difference from the test's perspective

Comment: @Matthew, good to know but worth a shot - it's definitely a potential factor in TCP receipt of data. I was about to reply with "why not send the full body?" but Evk has beaten me to it. If this is a low-level TCP comms, then I can see why you'd need something like this. However, if you're at a HTTP level, why not send the header + body? Or send two separate HTTP requests one with a body and one not? Then your low-level coms is taken care of and you can verify transmission.